# While using printf how to escape special characters in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, printf

I am trying to format a string with `printf` in shell, i will get input string from a file , that have special characters like `%,',"",,\user, \tan` etc.

How to escape the special characters that are in the input string ?

Eg

```
#!/bin/bash
# 

string='';
function GET_LINES() {

   string+="The path to K:\Users\ca, this is good";
   string+="\n";
   string+="The second line";
   string+="\t";
   string+="123"
   string+="\n";
   string+="It also has to be 100% nice than %99";

   printf "$string";

}

GET_LINES;
```

i am expecting this will print in the format i want like

```
The path to K:\Users\ca, this is good
The second line   123
It also has to be 100% nice than %99
```

But its giving unexpected out puts

```
./script: line 14: printf: missing unicode digit for \U
The path to K:\Users\ca, this is good
The second line 123
./script: line 14: printf: `%99': missing format character
It also has to be 100ice than
```

So how can i get rid of the special characters while printing.? `echo -e` also has the issue.

Comment: The possibility of `%` being in a parameter is exactly why you should never expand a parameter in the first argument to `printf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$' '` to enclose the newlines and tab characters, then a plain `echo` will suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash 

get_lines() {    
   local string
   string+='The path to K:\Users\ca, this is good'
   string+=$'\n'
   string+='The second line'
   string+=$'\t'
   string+='123'
   string+=$'\n'
   string+='It also has to be 100% nice than %99'

   echo "$string"
}

get_lines
```

I have also made a couple of other minor changes to your script. As well as making your FUNCTION_NAME lowercase, I have also used the more widely compatible function syntax. In this case, there's not a great deal of advantage (as `$' '` strings are a bash extension anyway) but there's no reason to use the `function func()` syntax as far as I'm aware. Also, the scope of `string` may as well be local to the function in which it is used, so I changed that too.

Output:

```
The path to K:\Users\ca, this is good
The second line 123
It also has to be 100% nice than %99
```

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
printf "%s\n" "$string"
```

See [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html)

Comment: it will print `The path to K:\Users\ca, this is good\nThe second line\t123\nIt also has to be 100% nice than %99`

Comment: the need \n,\t are not interperted

Comment: This is a really clean solution for some cases

Answer (score 10):

For the benefit of people who got here by clicking on the first search result after Googling "bash printf escaped", the `%q` formatter is used by printf to produce bash-escaped text.

For example:

```
$ printf "<<%q>>\n" 'foe fum' "fee fie"$'\n'
<<foe\ fum>>
<<$'fee fie\n'>>
```

From `man printf`:

```
%q     ARGUMENT is printed in a format that can be reused as shell
       input,  escaping  non-printable  characters with the 
       proposed POSIX $'' syntax.
```

Comment: Just add explanation for `%q` - causes printf to output the corresponding argument in a format that can be reused as shell input. https://man.archlinux.org/man/bash.1.en#printf

Answer (score 8):

May I remark that "man printf" shows clearly that a "%" character has to escaped by means of another "%"
so printf "%%" results in a single "%"