# Why use printf '%s\n' "message"?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
if [[ -z "$usr_name" ]]; then
   printf '%s\n' "No input entered"
   exit 1
```

What is the meaning of `'%s\n'` and why would you add it instead of just using:

```
printf "No input entered"
```

Comment: see https://man.cx/printf(3)

Comment: Did you try searching on your own? What did the search resulted in? Did you browse google for example for "how printf works?" or "what does %s in printf means?"?

Comment: I did do some searching but most answers I was not clear on the explanation. For example one answer stated "%s is a format specifier for printf command." which "causes the arguments to be concatenated without intervening spaces. It interprets the associated argument literally as string". I did not do any deep digging into printf.

Comment: The real question is, why would you use that instead of `printf '%s\n' 'No input entered' >&2`.  Error messages belong on stderr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958430/while-using-printf-how-to-escape-special-characters-in-shell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printf is used for format and print data. In the case of:

```
printf '%s\n' "No input entered"
```

%s represents a string place holder for the space separated string that follows and "\n" represents a line feed.

%s will then be substituted for "No input entered", followed by a line feed.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. To experiment, I tried running the script without '\n' included and $usr_name as an empty string. The "No input entered" output displayed on the same line as my prompt. Makes sense now.

Comment: No worries. If it helps your understanding, please take the time to up vote and accept the answer

Answer (score 4):

It's a defensive programming technique, hoping to prevent errors in which the format string contains unexpected directives or the number of arguments does not match the format string.  Also, putting the string in an argument reduces unnecessary escapes.  (Compare `printf '20%%\n'` and `printf '%s\n' '20%'`)  It also makes the format easier to see for the reader, helping prevent the mistake of forgetting the trailing newline.

Bottom line: it's a stylistic decision.  There's no functional difference between:

```
printf '%s\n' 'No input entered'
```

and

```
printf 'No input entered\n'
```

Comment: Though there _is_ a quite crucial difference between `printf "$variable\n"` and `printf '%s\n' "$variable"`, especially if `$variable` could contain user input.

Comment: *"a defensive programming technique"*... I like that; it kinda' says it all.

Answer (score 1):

With a fixed and nice string like that, there's not much difference.

But if the data came from a variable, you would *want* to use

```
printf "%s\n", "$var"
```

instead of expanding the variable in the format string, to defend against the possibility that the variable itself contains format specifiers (like `%s`), *or* starts with a dash, which would be taken as an option.

E.g. in Bash:

```
$ var=%s
$ printf "$var\n"

$ var=-foo
$ printf "$var\n"
bash: printf: -f: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

That's an empty line the first `printf` outputs because there is no argument to use to fill the `%s`. In the second, the error message should explain it.